# Regex Get all characters after first slash using java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get all the characters after first slash.
I have tried the following but its not working
Can anyone share any sample regex to get all characters after first slash

```
String pattern = "[A-Za-z\\s]|(?<=[A-Za-z\\s])/";
```

sample input - xx/abs-12345/67890
expected output - abs-12345/67890

Comment: Please add some sample of the text you're working on, what you get and how it doesn't fullfill your needs.

Comment: You seem to be familiar with look-behind so `(?<=/).*` is quite straightforward solution (depending on your goal you may want to let dot match all characters including line separators). If that is not what you ware asking then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: (?<=/).* - this is doing opposite

Comment: @user1514499 How are you using this regex? Did you use it to `find` match, or to `split` on it?

Comment: String pattern = "(?<=/).+";
  String replaced=in.replaceAll(pattern, "");  This is doing the opposite

Comment: `String replaced = in.replaceFirst("[^/]*/", "");`

Comment: Why so complicated? `[^\\]*\\(.*)` should make it too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the regex you need:

```
(?<=/).+
```

The lookbehind looks for a `/` and then matches every non-line-ending after it. Since the regex engine checks from left to right, it will always find the first slash.

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=/).+").matcher("xx/abs-12345/67890");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

You can even do this in one line, without regex.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(s.split("/")).skip(1).collect(Collectors.joining("/")));
```

`s` is the input string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need a regex to do that job. You can do like below.

```
String s = "123/abc23r";
String strAfterFirstSlash = s.substring(s.indexOf('/')+1,s.length());
char[] charsAfterFirstSlash = strAfterFirstSlash.toCharArray(); // If you need to get result in a char array
System.out.println(strAfterFirstSlash);
```

Output:

```
abc23r
```

Comment: I thought if he wants to character array.